# How to run a comparison within a string in php

Tags: php

If I have:

```
$compare = "5<6";
```

How do I look at the compare variable and return the value true. The input needs to be a string so taking away the `"` won't help. The string could be very complex so I'm looking for a function already in PHP which can run this, or something that someone has written before which can do this. I've tried the `eval()` function but that doesn't work, so:

```
$compare = "5<6";
echo eval($compare);
```

just errors. Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: From the docs: `...the passed code must be valid PHP....` for eval(): http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php

Comment: You should add `return` and `;`: `$compare="5<6";echo eval("return $compare;");`

Comment: Before using `eval` you should have read this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951373/when-is-eval-evil-in-php and at least it's top 3 answers.

Comment: echoing `true` will display `1` and echoing `false` will not display anything.

Comment: it is reading from another file so will only evaluate code that I have written

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using code evaluation functions are something that should be discouraged, because it may lead to a lot of security problems, but if you want to keep your logic that way, you must evaluate a valid code:

```
<?php
  $compare = "5 > 6";
  eval("\$result = $compare;");

  var_dump($result);
```

Your comparing `string`must be used inside the `eval` function like it would be done in the normal code, not expecting a return value. So what I changed in this sample code is that I used a variable named `$result` to store the value from the evaluated code.

As you will see when running this code, the `$result` will be a `boolean` value (`false` in this sample, because 5 is not greater than 6, obviously).

Comment: it's reading from another file, so it's only reading code that I'm writing into it

Comment: I'm just warning because you should avoid using this kind of function (in any environment/project, not just PHP). Of course you can use this kind of code, but you shouldn't :P Just be aware of the risks and (maybe) research a little bit about it, to see what are the problems that it will may lead (for future projects, perhaps). Anyway... hope it helped you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php 
$compare = "5<6";
eval('$output = '.$compare.';');
echo $output;
?>
```

Comment: Don't forget to sanitise the string before using eval.

Answer (score 0):

From PHP documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php

> **Caution** The eval() language construct is very dangerous because it allows execution of arbitrary PHP code. Its use thus is discouraged.
>   If you have carefully verified that there is no other option than to
>   use this construct, pay special attention not to pass any user
>   provided data into it without properly validating it beforehand.

You can display with `echo` directly:

```
<?php
$compare = '5<6';
echo $compare. "\n";
echo eval("return $compare;");
?>
```

Or You can store result in variable to display later:

```
<?php
$compare = '5<6';
echo $compare. "\n";
$result = eval("return $compare;");
echo $result;
?>
```

Be careful ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to avoid `eval` it's easy enough to parse comparison expressions. Just split the string on a comparison operator and return the result of the corresponding comparison.

```
function compare($expr) {
    $expr = preg_split('/(>=|<=|<|>|=)/', $expr, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
    list($lhs, $op, $rhs) = $expr;
    switch ($op) {
        case '<':  return $lhs <  $rhs;
        case '<=': return $lhs <= $rhs;
        case '>':  return $lhs >  $rhs;
        case '>=': return $lhs >= $rhs;
        case '==': return $lhs == $rhs;
    }
}
```

Apparently I missed the bit about "the string could be very complex" when I read the question initially, so this may not be helpful in your case, but I'll leave it here for future reference.