# Assigning a if statement's condition to a variable

Tags: php

Is it possible to assign a conditional statement into a variable and use it in an `if` statement? For example, I have the following code where the condition in the if statement will change from time to time:

```
<?php       
   $x = 2;
   
   //This "x > 5" value will come from a database
   $command = "x > 5";//Some times this value might be x > 5 || x == 1
  
   if($command)//This will always be true no matter what since the content of the $command is not empty
        echo "x is bigger than 5";
   else
        echo "x is smaller than 5";//I want this line to get executed since x is smaller than 5 in this case
?>
```

Expected output is `x is smaller than 5`, but what I get is `x is bigger than 5`

Comment: I wrote this answer to a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50280727/2734189. maybe you could use something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `eval()`. `$command` will have to contain `$` before the variables so it's valid PHP syntax.

```
$x = 2;
$command = '$x > 5';
$result = eval("return ($command);");
if ($result) {
    echo "x is bigger than 5";
} else {
    echo "x is smaller than 5";
}
```

Since `eval()` can execute arbitrary code, you should be extremely careful about what you allow to be put into `$command`.

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining this with an sample code. Apricate your help.

Comment: @DP. although it may be worth reading https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951373/when-is-eval-evil-in-php